# Any way to detect when user highlights or copies all/part of URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering if something like `window.getSelection()` would work for the URL, and if you could point me to any more reading material on the topic. Thank you!

Comment: i doubt given that URL bar is not part of the DOM model. but i am interested to see if there is a way too.

Comment: Here's a similar question that I found interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356222/how-can-one-detect-copying-a-link-in-a-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about detecting the selection made from the browser's address bar, the answer is simply **not possible**. JavaScript can read and write `window.location`, but it can't attach event handlers to it.

If the URL is located on the page itself, inside a text box or otherwise, there's the full arsenal of JavaScript at your disposal to find out exactly what has been selected, assuming JavaScript is enabled of course.